# Unable to setCustomValidity message on input validation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation

I have date type lightning input field:

`<lightning:input aura:id="startDate" type="date" dateStyle="short" value="{!v.startDate}" required="true" class="noAsterisk" onblur="{!c.handleValidationCheck}" />`

I've added a custom validation check function:

```
handleValidationCheck : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('********************************* we are inside the handleValidationCheck function');
    var inputCmp = component.find("startDate");
    var validity = component.find("startDate").get("v.validity");
    var inputCmpValue = inputCmp.get("v.value");
    console.log('***************************************** inputCmp value ' + inputCmpValue);
    console.log('***************************************** isValid ' + validity.valid);
    console.log('***************************************** valueMissing ' + validity.valueMissing);
    if(inputCmpValue === null) {
        console.log('************************************ we are inside the if branch');
        inputCmp.setCustomValidity("Please select a start date");
    }
    else {
        console.log('************************************ we are inside the else branch');
        inputCmp.setCustomValidity("");
    }
    inputCmp.reportValidity();
}
```

Updated method that includes the timeout function:

```
handleValidationCheck : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('********************************* we are inside the handleValidationCheck function');
    window.setTimeout( () => {
        var inputCmp = component.find("startDate");
        var validity = component.find("startDate").get("v.validity");
        var inputCmpValue = inputCmp.get("v.value");
        console.log('***************************************** inputCmp value ' + inputCmpValue);
        console.log('***************************************** isValid ' + validity.valid);
        console.log('***************************************** badInput ' + validity.badInput);
        console.log('***************************************** patternMismatch ' + validity.patternMismatch);
        console.log('***************************************** rangeOverflow ' + validity.rangeOverflow);
        console.log('***************************************** rangeUnderflow ' + validity.rangeUnderflow);
        console.log('***************************************** stepMismatch ' + validity.stepMismatch);
        console.log('***************************************** tooLong ' + validity.tooLong);
        console.log('***************************************** tooShort ' + validity.tooShort);
        console.log('***************************************** typeMismatch ' + validity.typeMismatch);
        console.log('***************************************** valueMissing ' + validity.valueMissing);
        if(inputCmpValue === null) {
            console.log('************************************ we are inside the if branch');
            inputCmp.setCustomValidity("Please select a start date");
        }
        else {
            console.log('************************************ we are inside the else branch');
            console.log('***************************************** inputCmp value ' + inputCmpValue);
            inputCmp.set('v.validity', {valid:true, valueMissing :false});
            console.log('***************************************** valueMissing ' + validity.valueMissing);
            inputCmp.setCustomValidity("");

        }
        inputCmp.reportValidity();
      }, 100);
}
```

isValid is always returning false because the valueMissing attribute is returning true even though the  input has a value and the console log shows that the else branch is entered. I'm trying to clear the validation error message `Complete this field.` and remove the red border around the input.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I've had this before too. `onblur` fires before any change is registered in the component and well before the `onchange` handler fires.

The only thing that I've every been able to do to fix is to use a timeout to delay the value retrieval so it is able to compute `isValid`.

You could of course roll your own component, but just adding the timeout works fine:

```
handleValidationCheck : function(component, event, helper) {
  window.setTimeout( () => {
    //the rest of your handler function
  }, 100);
}
```

You may be able to lower the timeout value, by quite a lot - but you'll need to tweak that for your particular UI.

Comment: I tried using the window.setTimeout function, but it's not working. I've updated the original post to include the code change. Is the implementation wrong?